# Is there a better way to get the column values from datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am have to check if the column exists and then go ahead and get the value from the first row. But with so many ifs it looks quite longed

```
theData = GetData();
            if (theData.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MyModel = new CustomModel();
                dataSetRow = theData.Rows[0];
                if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column1"))
                {
                    if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column1"], DBNull.Value)))
                    {
                        MyModel.Column1 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column1"]);
                    }
                }
                if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column2"))
                {
                    if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column2"], DBNull.Value)))
                    {
                        MyModel.Column2 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column2"]);
                    }
                }
                if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column3"))
                {
                    if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column3"], DBNull.Value)))
                    {
                        MyModel.Column3 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column3"]);
                    }
                }
                if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column4"))
                {
                    if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow["Column4"], DBNull.Value)))
                    {
                        MyModel.Column4 = Convert.ToString(dataSetRow["Column4"]);
                    }
                }
```

Is there a way I can make the code compact and not with so many ifs.

Comment: That's strange. Why do you check for `theData.Columns.Contains`. Can't you make sure database returns the columns properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to extract the repetitive piece of code into a separate method:

```
private string GetRowValue(DataRow dr, string columnName)
{
    if (dr.Table.Columns.Contains(columnName))
    {
        if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dr[columnName], DBNull.Value)))
        {
            return Convert.ToString(dr[columnName]);
        }
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Then call that to set your `MyModel` values:

```
dataSetRow = theData.Rows[0];

MyModel = new CustomModel
              {
                  MyModel.Column1 = GetRowValue(dataSetRow, "Column1"),
                  MyModel.Column2 = GetRowValue(dataSetRow, "Column2"),
                  ...
              };
```

Comment: Do I need to pass datSetRow each time since   dataSetRow = theData.Rows[0] in all the cases

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is slightly shorter. Is it enought compact for you?  ;)

```
 if (theData.Columns.Contains("Column1") && dataSetRow["Column1"] != DBNull.Value)
    MyModel.Column1 = dataSetRow["Column1"].ToString();
```

And by the way - this check `dataSetRow["Column1"] != DBNull.Value` is needed only if you don't want to get empty string when value in `dataSetRow` is DBNull (just because `DBNull.Value.ToString()` will produce `""`, not `NullReferenceException`).

Answer (score 1):

place all the column names in a list called columns, and I will suppose they are called the same way as the object properties

```
theData = GetData();
if (theData.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    MyModel = new CustomModel();
    dataSetRow = theData.Rows[0];
    foreach(column in columns)
    {
        if (theData.Columns.Contains(column))
        {
            if ((!object.ReferenceEquals(dataSetRow[column], DBNull.Value)))
            {
            MyModel.GetType().InvokeMember(column,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty,
            Type.DefaultBinder, MyModel, Convert.ToString(dataSetRow[column]));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the properties al called different, just iterate 2 list to call the right property name

Comment: Just that Reflection will Slow the application down

Comment: Yes it will, but it does what you have asked. Remove the whole switch. Check if the impact of using reflection is considerable against the code maintenance of lots of ifs